# Convert a single JSON to multiple jsons by taking one of the key values?

Tags: json, linux, amazon-web-services, shell, jq

**I currently have one json file as follows in terms of formatting:**

```
{
    "Comment":"json data",
    "Changes":[
        {
            "Action":"DELETE",
            "ResourceRecordSet":{
                "Name":"record1",
                "Type":"CNAME",
                "SetIdentifier":"record1-ap-northeast",
                "GeoLocation":{
                    "CountryCode":"JP"
                },
                "TTL":60,
                "ResourceRecords":[
                    {
                        "Value":"record1"
                    }
                ],
                "HealthCheckId":"ID"
            }
        },
        {
            "Action":"DELETE",
            "ResourceRecordSet":{
                "Name":"record2",
                "Type":"CNAME",
                "SetIdentifier":"record2-ap-south",
                "GeoLocation":{
                    "CountryCode":"SG"
                },
                "TTL":60,
                "ResourceRecords":[
                    {
                        "Value":"record2"
                    }
                ],
                "HealthCheckId":"ID"
            }
        },
        {
            "Action":"DELETE",
            "ResourceRecordSet":{
                "Name":"record3",
                "Type":"CNAME",
                "SetIdentifier":"record3-ap-west",
                "GeoLocation":{
                    "CountryCode":"IN"
                },
                "TTL":60,
                "ResourceRecords":[
                    {
                        "Value":"record3"
                    }
                ],
                "HealthCheckId":"ID"
            }
        },
        {
            "Action":"DELETE",
            "ResourceRecordSet":{
                "Name":"record4.",
                "Type":"CNAME",
                "SetIdentifier":"record4",
                "GeoLocation":{
                    "CountryCode":"*"
                },
                "TTL":60,
                "ResourceRecords":[
                    {
                        "Value":"record4-ap-west"
                    }
                ],
                "HealthCheckId":"ID"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The original file has 20000 such values for the "Changes key". I want to create a file with 830 values in each file and create as many files as it creates. In order to achieve this I need it in the below format.

```
{
    "Comment":"json data",
    "Changes":[
        {
            "Action":"DELETE",
            "ResourceRecordSet":{
                "Name":"record4.",
                "Type":"CNAME",
                "SetIdentifier":"record4", #830 such arrays in each file
                "GeoLocation":{
                    "CountryCode":"*"
                },
                "TTL":60,
                "ResourceRecords":[
                    {
                        "Value":"record4-ap-west"
                    }
                ],
                "HealthCheckId":"ID"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've created the below shell script to do this

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the input file name
input_file="input.json"

# Set the output file prefix
output_file_prefix="output"

# Set the number of objects per output file
objects_per_file=830

# Skip the first two lines of the input file
tail -n +3 "$input_file" > temp.json

# Get the total number of lines in the input file
total_lines=$(wc -l < temp.json)

# Calculate the number of output files needed
output_files=$(((total_lines + objects_per_file - 1) / objects_per_file))

# Split the input file into multiple output files
split -l $objects_per_file temp.json "$output_file_prefix"

# Loop through each output file and add the opening and closing square brackets
for file in "$output_file_prefix"*; do
  echo "[" > "$file".json
  cat "$file" >> "$file".json
  echo "]" >> "$file".json
  rm "$file"
done

# Remove the temporary file
rm temp.json
```

**By using this I am getting the output as expected but it is broken as it is considering 830 lines but not 830 arrays. **
**Format:**

```
#start of file
[
{
"Action": "DELETE",
"ResourceRecordSet":
{
  "Name": "record1",
  "Type": "CNAME",
  "SetIdentifier": "record1-ap-northeast",
  "GeoLocation": {
    "CountryCode": "JP"
  },
  "TTL": 60,
  "ResourceRecords": [
    {
      "Value": "record1"
    }
  ],
  "HealthCheckId": "ID"
}
},

#end of file
{
"Action": "DELETE",
"ResourceRecordSet":
{
"Action": "DELETE",
"ResourceRecordSet":
{
  "Name": "record4.",
  "Type": "CNAME",
  "SetIdentifier": "record4"
]
```

How do I achieve the required result. Due to the character limitation I cannot use more than 830 such arrays in each file?
I tried using jq tool to achieve this but I am completely new with it. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Do not parse JSON with split... Use a JSON aware parser. Python, Perl or jq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use jq, you will have to do it in two or three steps.  Each step, however, is very easy.

The first step uses jq with the -c option to create a JSONLines file with the JSON objects you want:

```
< input.json jq -c '
  (.Changes | _nwise(830)) as $C   # 830 per problem statement
  | .Changes = $C
' > output.jsonl
```

Next, partition output.jsonl into the files you want.  This can be done in many ways, e.g. using awk, or even the shell's `read`.

Finally, if you want the separate files to be "pretty-printed", you could use jq to do that in the obvious way.

Comment: I added it in this way and it worked
`< input.json jq -r --argjson size 830 '
  del(.Changes) as $object
  | (.Changes|_nwise($size) | ("\t", $object + {Changes:.} ))
' | awk '
      /^\t/ {fn++; next}
      { print >> "part-" fn ".json"}'`

Comment: @SaiKumar : as long as you're comfortable with output files literally named ::::::::::::::::: ::::::   `191.json` or `317771.json` ….

Answer (score 0):

so even assuming some of the `JSON` "rows" are compacted into 1 line (e.g. equivalent of `jq -c`) while others are pretty-printed in a tree format, then all you need is the right `regex` in `awk` to identify its row delimiter/sep (`"RS"`) :

```
gcat <( printf '%s' "$json_in_1$json_in_1$ajson_in_1" | jq -c      ) 
     <( printf '%s\n%s\n%s' "$json_in_1" "$json_in_1" "$json_in_1" ) |
```

> ```
>  {m,g,n}awk '
>  BEGIN { RS = (_ = "[[:space:]]*") (__ = "[}]") \
>               (_)__ (_)"[]]" (_)__ (FS =  "\n") "?"
>         ORS = (_ = "}")_     ("]")_ FS
>         OFS = "\f\r\t"
>        _+=_^= __ = (_<_)
>  } { 
>      printf(" NR # %d | NF = %d :: %s>>>>%s%s%.*s%s>>>>%s",
>               NR, NF, FS, FS, $__, _<NF, FS, ORS, FS, FS) }'
> ```

```
 NR # 1 | NF = 1 :: 
>>>>
{"Comment":"json data","Changes":[{"Action":"DELETE","ResourceRecordSet":{"Name":"record4.","Type":"CNAME","SetIdentifier":"record4","GeoLocation":{"CountryCode":"*"},"TTL":60,"ResourceRecords":[{"Value":"record4-ap-west"}],"HealthCheckId":"ID"}}]}
>>>>
 NR # 2 | NF = 1 :: 
>>>>
{"Comment":"json data","Changes":[{"Action":"DELETE","ResourceRecordSet":{"Name":"record4.","Type":"CNAME","SetIdentifier":"record4","GeoLocation":{"CountryCode":"*"},"TTL":60,"ResourceRecords":[{"Value":"record4-ap-west"}],"HealthCheckId":"ID"}}]}
>>>>
 NR # 3 | NF = 19 :: 
>>>>
{
    "Comment":"json data",
    "Changes":[
        {
            "Action":"DELETE",
            "ResourceRecordSet":{
                "Name":"record4.",
                "Type":"CNAME",
                "SetIdentifier":"record4",
                "GeoLocation":{
                    "CountryCode":"*"
                },
                "TTL":60,
                "ResourceRecords":[
                    {
                        "Value":"record4-ap-west"
                    }
                ],
                "HealthCheckId":"ID"
}}]}
>>>>
 NR # 4 | NF = 19 :: 
>>>>
{
    "Comment":"json data",
    "Changes":[
        {
            "Action":"DELETE",
            "ResourceRecordSet":{
                "Name":"record4.",
                "Type":"CNAME",
                "SetIdentifier":"record4",
                "GeoLocation":{
                    "CountryCode":"*"
                },
                "TTL":60,
                "ResourceRecords":[
                    {
                        "Value":"record4-ap-west"
                    }
                ],
                "HealthCheckId":"ID"
}}]}
>>>>
 NR # 5 | NF = 19 :: 
>>>>
{
    "Comment":"json data",
    "Changes":[
        {
            "Action":"DELETE",
            "ResourceRecordSet":{
                "Name":"record4.",
                "Type":"CNAME",
                "SetIdentifier":"record4",
                "GeoLocation":{
                    "CountryCode":"*"
                },
                "TTL":60,
                "ResourceRecords":[
                    {
                        "Value":"record4-ap-west"
                    }
                ],
                "HealthCheckId":"ID"
}}]}
>>>>
```

then once you've been able to isolate individual `"Change Key"` records, then outputing every 830 rows should be relative straight-forward.

you can pipe the output of that further downstream to confirm the output is valid `JSON` via :

> ```
> ... | awk '/^[{]/,/[}][}][]][}]$/' | jq
> ```

as long as the input structure is very well defined, then `awk` can handle `JSON`s just fine instead of needing a dedicated parser.